# Custom Object resets its values after initializing from constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I create (if not exists) a new ViewModel Instance via the IMessenger (MVVM Light Toolkit) and pass a custom Object trough the constructor, which is a Property of my MainViewModel.
In this ViewModel I set it to a Property too and using it e.g. for a Command Execute Method. But when I trigger the Command via Binding, the custom Object Property looses its values.
I already debugged and saw, that the object get's passed correctly with its values, but after initializing from the constructor its empty (Not null, just empty Properties).

My custom Object

```
public class CustomObject : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    // etc...
}
```

I create the ViewModel like this

```
public CustomObject CustomObj
{
    get { return _customObj; }
    set { Set(ref _customObj, value); }
}

_customViewModel = new CustomViewModel(CustomObj, _dataService);
```

The ViewModel

```
public CustomViewModel(CustomObject obj, IDataService dataService)
{
    _dataService = dataService;

    // Here it sets correctly the Object
    CustomObj = obj;
}

public CustomObject CustomObj
{
    get { return _customObj; }
    set { Set(ref _customObj, value); }
}

// Even before the Command is triggered, the Object is already empty
public ICommand SomeCommand => new RelayCommand<string>(async s =>
{
    var someThing = await _dataService.GetSomeData(CustomObj.Id);

    // Stuff...
}
```

They are registered in the SimpleIoC Container as well, if that matters.

What could result that?

Comment: What is resolve strategy for your objects In IoC? I mean, check if you get new object every time you call Resolve

Comment: @ВасилийШапенко I just registered them like that
    `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CustomObject>();
     SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
     SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CustomViewModel>();`
Should I use them any way different?

Comment: Take a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297014/does-the-mvvm-light-simpleioc-support-singletons